# How to use a JWT internally and an opaque token externally for microservices using spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, microservices

*(This is for a university project so keep in mind that there is slightly less security than in a real-world application and its only an API no front-end)*

I am implementing a microservices-based app and need to implement authentication and authorization. I was thinking of using JWTs since I can authenticate the user and also add their privileges into the JWT. However, I saw that they can be altered fairly easily due to the not ideal algorithms used for the signature.
I looked at this [article](https://medium.com/tech-tajawal/microservice-authentication-and-authorization-solutions-e0e5e74b248a)

[and chose this architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmkwB.png)

However I can't seem to find whether spring has functionality for mapping opaque keys to JWTs in the gateway service, so I can give my user an opaque key and use a JWT internally.

Comment: _"they can be altered fairly easily"_ mind to elaborate on what you mean? Because actually JWTs cannot be altered by unauthorized parties…

Comment: https://cyberpolygon.com/materials/security-of-json-web-tokens-jwt/ the key can be mined with symmetric algorithms

Comment: You can avoid that simply by using an asymmetric algorithm like RS256.

Comment: Note: the article you are referencing claims that RS256 is symmetric, which is incorrect.

Comment: thanks a lot, this simplifies things greatly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as [slauth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6756090/slauth) mentioned in the comments, the need for an opaque token can be avoided by using an asymmetric algorithm for signing the JWTs thus making them tamper-proof